# Saving A Game In Replit And Loading To Start From That Place Where Saved

Tags: python

I have a code for a text adventure game we are making at school, how do i make it so that if the user decides to leave at some point in the game and decide to play back later, when they do come back to the game, itll load to the place where they left off?

Here's my code so far

```py
#importations
import random
import replit
import time
#inventory/statistics
backpack = ["flashlight", "a water bottle", "Am apple", "A blanket"]

#the beginning, linked to the last code
name = input("Welcome to Medolxa adventurer! Please type your name, to begin this mysterious adventure: \n")
time.sleep(1)
print("Great, welcome to Medolxa",name,"!") 
time.sleep(1)
replit.clear()




def horror_start():
    print("As you progress further into the party, you seem to be having migraines")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("g")
    



#after secondary
def chorus():
    time.sleep(1)
    food = input("Your tummy rumbles, will you get something from the fridge or an apple from your backpack: \n")
    if food == "apple" or food == "Apple":
        f = open("xp.txt", "w")
        f.write("110")
        f.close()
        h = open("hungerbar.txt", "w")
        h.write("100%")
        h.close()
        print("You've eaten an apple, increasing you HP to 110! Your hunger bar is now full")
    elif food == "fridge" or food == "Fridge":
       food2 =  input("There is 2 slices of cake, and pasta, which one will you choose")
       if food2 == "pasta":
           f = open("xp.txt", "w")
           f.write("179")
           f.close()
           h = open("hungerbar.txt", "w")
           print("You chose pasta, which increases your HP to 179!")
           time.sleep(1)
           print("Your hunger bar has increased to full!")
       elif food2 == "cake" or food2 == "Cake":
           f = open("xp.txt", "w")
           f.write("100")
           f.close()
           h = open("hungerbar.txt", "w")
           h.write("76%")
           h.close()
           print("You chose cake, and your tummy seems to hurt, your HP reduces to 100")
           time.sleep(1)
           print("Your hunger bar increases only a little bit, to 76%")
    else:
        f = open("xp.txt", "w")
        f.write("70")
        f.close()
        h = open("hungerbar.txt", "w")
        h.write("70%")
        h.close()
        print("You decide to not eat anything, which reduces your HP to 70.")
    print("Your current statistics are mentioned below: \n")
    f = open("xp.txt", "r")
    print(f.read(), "is your xp status")
    h = open("hungerbar.txt", "r")
    print(h.read(), "is your hungerbar")
    g = open("thirstbar.txt", "r")
    print(g.read(), "is your thirstbar")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Ended for now.")
    horror_start()


#after main subroutime
def secondary():
    time.sleep(1)
    print("The door opens... ")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("You see your friends and they welcome you, with a box of...chocolates?")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("The chocolates look mouldy, and somehow it seems to have melted")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("You step inside the house, and you feel the heat vibrating onto your skin. ")
    time.sleep(2)
    drinks = input("There is music playing in the background, you see a fridge of drinks: emerge, monster, fanta, coke and pepsi, which one will you take?: \n")
    if drinks == "e" or drinks == "emerge" or drinks == "Emerge":
        emerge = input("You chose emerge, would you like to drink it now? (y/n) \n")
        if emerge  == "y":
            f = open("xp.txt", "w")
            f.write("170")
            f.close()
            print("You drank the emerge, increasing your hp to 170!")
        elif emerge == "n":
            backpack.append("Emerge Drink")
            print("This has now been added to your backpack")
    elif drinks == "m" or drinks == "monster" or drinks == "Monster":
        monster = input("You chose monster, would you like to drink it now (y/n?): \n")
        if monster == "y":
            f = open("xp.txt", "w")
            f.write("156")
            f.close()
            print("You drank the monster, increasing your hp to 156")
        elif monster == "n":
            backpack.append("Monster")
            print("This has now been added to your backpack")
    elif drinks == "f" or drinks == "fanta" or drinks == "Fanta":
        fanta = input("You chose fanta, would you like to drink it now? (y/n) \n")
        if fanta == "y":
            f = open("xp.txt", "w")
            f.write("159")
            f.close()
            print("You drank your fanta, which increased your hp to 159!")
        elif fanta == "n":
            backpack.append("Fanta")
            print("This has now been added to your backpack!")
    elif drinks == "c" or drinks == "coke" or drinks == "Coke" or drinks == "Cola" or drinks == "cola":
        coke = input("You now have coke, would you like to drink it now?: (y/n)  \n")
        if coke == "y":
            f = open("xp.txt", "w")
            f.write("162")
            f.close()
            print("You decided to drink your coke, which increased your HP to 162!")
        elif coke == "n":
            backpack.append("Coke")
            print("This has now been stored to your backpack!")
    elif drinks == "p" or drinks == "pepsi" or drinks == "Pepsi":
        pepsi = input("You now have pepsi, would you like to drink it: (y/n \n )")
        if pepsi == "y":
            f = open("xp.txt", "w")
            f.write("166")
            f.close()
            print("You have drank pesi, which increases your HP to 166!")
        elif pepsi == "n":
            backpack.append("Pepsi")
            print("Pepsi, has now been added to your backpack")
    print("Your xp is now mentioned below:")
    f = open("xp.txt", "r")
    print(f.read())
    time.sleep(4)
    replit.clear()
    chorus()

        




            



#this is the second part of the game
def main():
    print("Hint: Use these wisely, your HP will decrease any time if used insufficiently, your HP will be mentioned throughout the game...")
    time.sleep(4)
    pickup  =  input("You continue your treacherous path, down to the river valley, you find a spare water bottle lying around but, there is bound to be many more in the party. Still, do you decide to take one? (y/n): \n")
    if pickup == "y":
        backpack.append("Another Water Bottle")
        inv = input("Would you like to see your inventory now?: (y/n) \n")
        if inv == "y":
            print(backpack, "now you have these all...")
            secondary()
        elif inv == "n":
            secondary()
    elif pickup == "n":
        print("You walk down the marshes and finally find your way to the house, there is a full light view insie the house and there is music playing.")
        time.sleep(4)
        replit.clear()
        secondary()









#the introduction to the game
def intro():
    time.sleep(1)
    print("/  \    /  \ ____ |  |   ____  ____   _____  ____ ")
    print("\   \/\/   // __ \|  | _/ ___\/  _ \ /     \_/ __ ")
    print(" \        /\  ___/|  |_\  \__(  <_> )  Y Y  \  ___/ ")
    print("  \__/\  /  \___  >____/\___  >____/|__|_|  /\___>")
    print("Loading...")
    print("Did you know: This game has many secrets, from the drinks you take to the path of redemption itself, get ready to play!")
    time.sleep(4)
    print("The console will be cleared to give you an adjustable and fun experience to play")
    time.sleep(5)
    replit.clear()
    print("Game Started...")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("You leave the boat and head onto the wet  land, the others follow just behind you")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("You seem to be in the middle of nowhere, the grass is wet")
    time.sleep(2)
    inventory = input("You have a backpack, would you like to see what is inside?: (y/n) \n")
    if inventory == "n":
     main()
    elif inventory == "y":
     print(backpack, "these are  all you have right now!")
     main()



#beginning (to make the code work, this is the main menu)
start = True
while start==True:
 yes = "y"
 no = "n"
 game = input("This game is a horror, mysterious game, would you like to continue?: (y/n)  \n")
 if game == yes:
    print("Alrighty, let's go!")
    start = False
    intro()
 elif game == no:
    print("Game has ended, come back once you're ready!")
    start = False
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Without seeing your code it's hard to give you specific advice.  However, saved state is typically accomplished by writing the data to a file and then loading it when the game starts.

Comment: my code contains a bunch of subroutines and such for the game but ill edit it now!

Comment: Try to limit it to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: A typical simple way to save game state is in a file. A typical format often used is a json file.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need persistent storage such as a database or a file.

`sqlite3` module is a good start, but `json` data dumps would work as well, if you don't want to use a remote network connection.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/persistence.html